# pyppeteer (+ asyncio) not playing nicely on AWS Severless

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-asyncio, puppeteer

I'm trying to set up an AWS Lambda handler that involves using pyppeteer (the python-port of headless Chrome in node.js) to take a screenshot.

```
def getSavePath():
    path = "picture_{}.png".format(random.randint(100, 1000))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(._screenshot(path))
    print("Done taking screenshot...")

    return path

async def _screenshot(path):
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL, {"waitUntil": "networkidle0"})

    textBox = await page.querySelector('[name="section"]')
    submitButton = await page.querySelector('#submit')
    canvas = await page.querySelector("#canvas")

    await textBox.click({"clickCount": 3});
    await textBox.type(self.wkt)
    await submitButton.click()

    await canvas.screenshot({'path': path})
    await browser.close()
```

When I run this locally, the screenshot gets taken and the path gets returned correctly.

When I run this on AWS Lambda, I'm getting:

```
    loop.run_until_complete(._screenshot(path))
  File "/var/task/asyncio/base_events.py", line 296, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
  File "/var/task/asyncio/tasks.py", line 516, in async
    raise TypeError('A Future or coroutine is required')
TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required
/var/task/slash.py:50: RuntimeWarning: coroutine '_screenshot' was never awaited
```

Any thoughts on why this would work locally but not on Lambda?

I'm using Python version 3.6 both locally and on Lambda.

Comment: I've suddenly started getting a similar problem (works locally on 3.6 but the same error on lambda, but with another package) after updating asyncio (not the package itself).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? I'm having the exact same issue